# django rest frame work not recognized yet installed

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have installed django REST framework and added it on INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py very well as instructed by the official documentation of DRF. but when I import it in seriealizers.py to use it's packages or files like this from *rest_framework* import serializers  that
rest_framework word is coming underlined by the yellow line like it is not recognized and from that I can't access what is included in like serializers because it doesn't known.

I have tried to create and recreate the virtual envirnoment but it didn't work
I also uninstalled DRF and reinstall it again but it didn't worked too

Comment: When you run the app with `python manage.py runserver` does it give any error message? Also, are you using VS Code or Pycharm?